# Apply limit to each condition in an $or query?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a chatroom application written in Meteor, using MongoDB. Each chatroom contains many messages, and a user can join multiple chatrooms. I'd like to create a query that fetches the 200 most recent messages from each chatroom for all the chatrooms that a given user is in. I'm doing something like this:

`// These are the ids of the chatrooms the user is currently in
var conditions = [{chatroomId: 1}, {chatroomId: 2}];
Messages.find({$or: conditions}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}, limit: 200});`

However, naturally, this limit applies to the entire query; so the user might end up with 180 messages from one room and 20 from another. Worse, as new messages are added, it's inconsistent which room has old messages culled away.

I could increase the limit as the user joins more chatrooms, but that could lead to them having 5 messages in two chatrooms and 590 in the third.

Is there a way to apply a slice or limit to each condition in the or? I'm publishing this as a Meteor publication, so I need to return a single cursor.

Comment: You cannot do that as the "limit" applies to the whole set of results and not just a single condition in the selection. As you should be able to imagine, you actually want the combined results of several queries. You can do this server side with [`async.concat`](https://github.com/caolan/async#concatarr-iterator-callback) or possibly any other form where you combine the results from multiple queries, ideally executed in parallel. But this does mean several queries. It's "possible" with `.aggregate(), but it does mean keeping the whole list and then stripping out results. Not nice for 200 items

Comment: Unfortunately if you return multiple cursors in an array, they currently must all be from different collections. Otherwise, you could have just pushed the cursors for each chatroom into an array and return the array of cursors. Meteor hopes to "lift the restriction in the future".

Answer (score 0):

You can't apply a limit to only a portion of the result set, so the only way to accomplish this is with multiple subscriptions. Here's some sample code using template subscriptions. You'll need to modify it for your specific use case.

**server**

```js
// Returns a limited set of messages for one specific chat room.
Meteor.publish('messages', function(chatroomId, limit) {
  check(chatroomId, String);
  check(limit, Number);

  var options = {sort: {createdAt: -1}, limit: limit};
  return Messages.find({chatroomId: chatroomId}, options);
});
```

**client**

```js
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  messages: function() {
    // Read all of the messages (you may want to restrict these by room),
    // sort them, and return the first 100 across all.
    return _.chain(Messages.find().fetch())
      .sortBy(function(message){return -message.createdAt.getTime();})
      .first(100)
      .value();
  }
});

Template.myTemplate.onCreated(function() {
  // Subscribe to multiple chat rooms - here we are assuming the ids are
  // stored in the current context - modify this as needed for your use case.
  this.subscribe('messages', this.chatroomId1, 100);
  this.subscribe('messages', this.chatroomId2, 100);
});
```

Comment: Seems like this would be really slow if the number of chatrooms is large and the number of messages in each is small.

Comment: Agreed. This becomes unpleasant as a function of the number of chatrooms the user belongs to. There may be better heuristics for choosing the limits, e.g. if there are > 5 rooms, reduce the limit to 20 each. If this setup proves unmanageable, then I'd recommend changing the nature of the problem. Perhaps storing the last N messages for each user in a separate collection.

Comment: How about copying the results server side to a temporary collection? Might be faster if you were only looking at a subset of fields. Then publication can happen in one shot.

Comment: Looks like Meteor doesn't support Mongo's `cloneCollection()` which would make that easier/faster.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that simply having a dynamic number of `.find()`s, one for each room, would address the situation.